# How to lock a database row for a fixed time interval?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, distributed-transactions

I have two databases. I have to commit my transaction only when both the entries are available in those two databases. For that, I planned to use a 2 phase similar algorithm. But the implementation is getting somewhat tricky.

I thought about implementation as follows:

- I query both the databases for the respective entries and if available, I will lock them so that no other user can access them and return success.
- If i get success from both, I commit them. or else i will remove the lock, if any of the entry is locked.

I also have to handle faults, so the lock should be released after a timeout if an explicit release query hasn't been sent.

My question is, how to explicitly lock the rows for no concurrent access to multiple clients and is there any better implementation that I should think about? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: This is already a solved problem. Use distributed transaction using a JTA transaction manager.

Comment: I am planning to do this project without any use of existing libraries. If you can suggest some pure java and sql implementation, I would be grateful. BTW Thank you for the answer

Comment: @Deadpool Why on earth would you want to re-invent this? Will you be writing your own JDBC driver too?

Comment: I am studying distributed systems course and i want to get my basics right i suppose :D

Comment: If you are seriously making a study of this topic, I suggest you read the source-code for an existing solution, and then post here when you have a narrowly-focused question about a very specific technical point. Having us help you re-discover the various issues to a known solved problem is a poor use of your time and ours.

Comment: Sleeps in general aren't a solution to anything. They are usually evidence of a deeper problem, or the lack of a proper solution.